# extend keys() and other generator method of Map Class in javascript

Tags: javascript, inheritance, iterator, generator

I need to use an object as keys for my map, therefore I extended the map class that stringifies the object passed, like so

```
class CoordMapper extends Map {
    set = (k: ISquareCoordinate, v: Array<ISquareCoordinate>) => {
        const stringifiedKey = JSON.stringify(k)
        return super.set(stringifiedKey,v)
    }

    get = (k: ISquareCoordinate) => {
        const stringifiedKey = JSON.stringify(k)
        return super.get(stringifiedKey)
    }
}
```

As far as I understand keys(), values() and entries() are generator methods, therefore I can do something like

```
* keys() {
   const keysArr = [...super.keys()]
   for (const key of keysArr){
      yield JSON.parse(key)
   }
}
```

But this causes me to load all the keys which I wish to avoid, is there a better way?

EDIT:
While Map does take in objects as keys but it only checks objects by reference. As an example

```
let newMap = Map()
const obj1 = {'a': 1, 'b' :2}
newMap.set(obj1, 123)
const copyObj1 = {...obj1}
console.log(newMap.get(obj1)) //returns 123
console.log(newMap.get(copyObj1)) //returns undefined
```

And i need the second `console.log` to return 123 aswell

Comment: A [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) can already use objects as key, no need to create this functionality yourself.

Comment: You don't actually need to convert `super.keys()` to an array beforehand. Just iterate directly: `for (const key of super.keys()) { yield JSON.parse(key) }`.

Comment: @Reyno it can but then it checks equality by reference and not value. Edited to add more details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than collecting all the parent values into an array, just iterate over them directly:

```
* keys() {
   const parentKeyIterator = super.keys();
   for (const key of parentKeyIterator){
      yield JSON.parse(key)
   }
}
```

That way, the laziness of the iterator is retained: each time `next()` is called on your extended iterator, it will call `next()` on `parentKeyIterator` once, then reach your `yield` statement, and pause.

Comment: Omg ofcourse, yes thank you so much. That was painstakingly obvious

Answer (score 1):

Just in case someone stumble here in the future, there's [a stage-3 proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-iterator-helpers) which, if approved, would add syntactic sugar for iterators so that you can do something like this:

```js
class CoordMapper extends Map {
  *keys() {
    yield* super.keys().map(key => JSON.parse(key));
  }
}
```

Try it (this doesn't work yet):

```js
console.config({ maximize: true });

class CoordMapper extends Map {
  set(k, v) {
    return super.set(JSON.stringify(k), v)
  }
  get(k) {
    return super.get(JSON.stringify(k));
  }
  *keys() {
    console.log(super.keys())
    yield* super.keys().map(JSON.parse);
  }
}

const c = new CoordMapper();

c.set({ foo: 'bar' }, 0);
c.set({ baz: 42 }, 1);
c.set({ qux: { lorem: 'ipsum' } }, [null, undefined]);

for (const key of c.keys()) {
  console.log(key);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: `map(JSON.parse)` is generally a bad idea because `parse` accepts more than one argument.

Comment: @gog You're right, thanks! I rarely use the `reviver` argument so I totally forgot that it exists.